# Google Maps Property Information, size and erf number

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to get the property number of a specific address. I am from South Africa we call it the erf number here. In the Erf Number Image below is an example of the erf number found from an real estate software used to upload a property. The image below is what I am searching for.

[image]

I have found a example of the place_id but that is not the same like this

[image]

I am also trying to get the size of the property. I'm coding the maps in HTML and JavaScript. Thank You

Comment: what are those images from? and why do you think google maps provides this information?

Comment: Hi Craicerjack, the image is from a real estate software you need to subscribe and pay for it if you want to use it. The software is using google maps that is why i guess google maps will have the information. It is maybe possible that all the erf numbers is already inserted by themselfs or through another application or addon.

Comment: I dont think google maps have this information, its more likely that software is building on google maps with this information.

Comment: Thank you Craicerjack. I will try a different way to get it then. Do you think I can get the size of the property from google maps?

Comment: I dont think so. I have seen nothing in their api that would give you such a thing. You can get the area of a selected section of the map passing in lat and lngs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance

Comment: Thank you. I will try to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a few years ago that you asked the question so I hope you got it sorted out. If not, use the map from the Surveyor General's office online. It gives you all the cadastral info you need.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31406186)